What purity of LOX is required for use in rocket engines?
Can any one suggest, is it necessary to check purity of LOX before it is used in an engine? What are the impurities which can affect its performance? What types of tests can we perform to check its purity by which standard?

see https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20080026088/downloads/20080026088.pdf

@ScienceSnake The close votes were because Khan is asking multiple questions, but I don't personally think these are diverse enough questions to require multiple Qs to handle.

tl;dr

The shuttle program, at least, investigated LOX purity at one point.
The major impurities for us were argon and nitrogen.
The tests done were chemical analysis (no further detail).
The shuttle program certainly had a purity requirement for the LOX they purchased, but I can't find it. (The test stand requirement was for 99.2% pure LOX to be delivered, but I can't find the flight tank requirement)

When I worked in the shuttle integration office in the early 2000s, there was a big investigation going on into the effects of "LOX purity". This was kicked off because the shuttle main engines in flight mostly had slightly better performance than expected from when they were run on the test stands (each engine was tested individually to generate what was called "tag data": flowrates and thrust (and hence Isp)).
While better in-flight performance might sound good, the propellant reserves were calculated based on the test stand results, and underperforming test stand results mean that you load too much reserve LOX, and end up lifting propellant mass to space which could have been used for payload.
It was eventually determined that the major difference was due to the fact that the ground test stand LOX tanks were pressurized with N2 instead of expensive helium (used in the flight system) and the N2 ended up contaminating the LOX. (This had been known since 1965 and reiterated in 1989 but apparently forgotten in the NASA corporate knowledge).
The "natural" impurity is argon which may actually exist in the LOX at higher amounts than that of the N2.
I suspect this investigation was the inspiration for Section VI in the 2011 paper Summary of Results from
Space Shuttle Main Engine Off-Nominal Testing titled "LOX Purity Sampling"
In that section the rationale for investigation is given as

A test with low LOX purity can result in flying an engine with a lower oxidizer-to-fuel mixture
ratio as the engine will not require as much oxidizer to maintain chamber pressure (due to higher LOX
purity seen on launch day). That condition results in flying with more LOX than is needed for a given
mission and that difference in margin could be the difference between achieving the planned orbit or
having to abort (e.g. low fuel level cutoff) due to unplanned ascent performance dispersions.

which is exactly what we were looking into in the SE&I office.
They did sample the LO2 twice; once the attempt failed, the second one worked, but they were unable to make the desired comparison. Somehow, though, they conclude

that, even under the most favorable dilution
conditions, LOX purity is not a meaningful test stand concern.


"once the attempt failed, the second one worked, but they were unable to make the desired comparison. Somehow, though, they conclude that, even under the most favorable dilution conditions, LOX purity is not a meaningful test stand concern."
This is such a NASA thing to do. Literally, we can't test it therefore it's unimportant.

It's weird that they "forgot" about N2 contamination. Anyone working with liquid nitrogen is aware of the reverse problem: liquid N2 that spends too much time being exposed to the atmosphere picks up O2, turning your nice inert N2 into something more reactive.

@PM2Ring they forgot about being head-in-the-sand managers too after the Challenger failure. Never overestimate the ability of bureaucracies to overlook the obvious. Plus it's pretty incredible how much MSFC (who ran the test stands) and JSC management despised each other.

The biggest concern with high-pressure oxygen plumbing is foreign object debris (FOD) contamination. Solids, even extremely small solids, present in LOX (or GOX) pose an ignition risk if they strike the walls of plumbing or working of valves at high velocity, as they can locally cause enough heating to ignite the wall material.
Even very small (by industry standards) ox valve explosions are remarkably violent things, part metal fire & part BLEVE (boiling liquid/expanding vapor explosion). Also very expensive--cryogenic oxygen-compatible valves are not cheap.
E.g.:
 Source: https://x.com/Pad33space/status/1815083382923313456
The choice of wall material for inertness (needs more heat to begin ignition, e.g. avoiding aluminum unless hard-anodized, the use of 316 over other steels, the inclusion of brass), the reduction of of fod size (less energy to be released as heat in a collision), the selection or design of straight-flow valves (eg ball or sleeve instead of pintle), the elimination of turns in oxygen plumbing harder than 90%, and the reduction of oxygen flow velocities by use of larger plumbing; are all techniques that can mitigate the metal ignition risk.
Relevant-ish: https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0608260.pdf
My interpretation of your question is that you want to know about the degree fod elimination or reduction. My understanding is that the accepted criterion is "as much as is practicably possible". Most sources of contamination will come from storage tankage or valve fouling. From my experience, extensive cleaning (both chemical & mechanical) is the most important part of oxygen-system fod reduction.
